# Search records by Prefix in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hye All!
i have a question regarding Mysql Database.Right now i have two tables

```
1.USERS  `(columns= id|username|password|sku-prefix)`.

2.ORDERS `(columns = order_id|order_name|sku-code)`.
```

In sku_prefix column i stored prefix like SN, HA.
In sku-code column i stored sku-code like SN001,HA008.

now i have to make a query for users to select records from ORDERS table according to sku-prefix match with sku_code and fetch records for the user logged in.

how can i do that?

Comment: Fix your data structure to have a proper junction table.  That is, a table with one row per order and sku, often called something like `OrderLines` or `OrderProducts`.

Comment: What happens when one user wants to see more than one SKU. Redesign your database now before you get to a place where you cannot make it do anything useful.

Comment: actually users will allowed to see only their sku products

Comment: i just want to fetch records by matching prefix with sku code. can you help in it?

Comment: Yea, currently. But as soon as user gets used to this they are going to ask for more and this structure wont suppost it, Always design databases for flexibility. Or the second phase of the probject will entail a total rewrite

Comment: @RiggsFolly every user has only one sku prefix allowed which he used on his products like if i have prefix SN then i just make codes like SN001 to onwards but SN will remin with code

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. First read Userdata from database `$query_text= "SELECT sku-prefix FROM USERS WHERE username={$username}"` where $username is variable with logged-in user name. And let's suppose you store recieved sku-prefix in `$sku_prefix` variable. Then execute another query to get what you need: `$query_text= "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE sku-code LIKE '{$sku_prefix}%'"`

Comment: hey Alex i have thi logic in my mind but it fails when i have sku prefixes like SNN or SNA. if i use LIKE it will fetch these records too